# Infinite dimensional generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: path-integral, integration, calculus

Can we generalize the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) dt = f(x)$$

to path integrals

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{q(0)=0}^{q(1)=x} \mathcal F[q] \, D q = \,  ?$$

Comment: If the path integral would have a formal definition, then perhaps yes.